# What is the difference between mongoimport upsert and merge

Tags: mongodb, merge, upsert

I am trying to load data from a file created using mongoexport in one server into another. New documents  must be inserted, existing ones must be updated with data in the file.I see that documentation refers to upsert and merge options, but the difference is not obvious to me.

Comment: URL to documentation?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/ . The examples gave some more clarity - looks like "upsert replaces existing attributes - i.e. completely replaces the document. merge does not remove existing attributes . It just adds new attributes. If the value of an existing attribute has changed in the file, does it get overwritten?

Comment: It does which is also covered in the example.

Comment: Aah yes, crystal@example.com gets replaced with crystal.duncan@example.com, missed that. Thanks.